# Functional programming question: How to apply a function to the same column in a dataframe that has multiindex columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, functional-programming

Suppose the below dataframe.  How does one apply a function (e.g. `np.log`) to both column `e`'s below?  I'm pretty sure one needs to use `apply` or `map` but never done this with a dataframe that has multiindex columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("a", "d"), ("a", "e"), ("b", "d"), ("b","e")))
df  

    a       b
    d   e   d   e
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
```

Desired output:

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['e'])] = df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['e'])].apply(np.log).round(2)

df
    a         b
    d     e   d     e
0   1  0.69   3  1.39
1   5  1.79   7  2.08
2   9  2.30  11  2.48
3  13  2.64  15  2.77
```

I realize I could use an inelegant method such as the above but would like to utilize functional programming techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` and select on the columns axis:

```py
# for this transform and apply are interchangeable
df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'e'] = df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'e'].transform(np.log).round(2)

df
    a         b
    d     e   d     e
0   1  0.69   3  1.39
1   5  1.79   7  2.08
2   9  2.30  11  2.48
3  13  2.64  15  2.77
```

In response to your comments, you can use a dictionary comprehension (does not offer any performance gain/ clarity, in my opinion though):

```py
result = {key : ent.transform(np.log).round(2) 
          for key, ent in df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'e'].items()}

df.update(result)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to achieve the same result via a list comprehension?

Comment: why would you want a list comprehension? it does not offer any vectorisation benefits

Comment: Just wondering for conceptual purposes.

Comment: Separately but related, is it possible to keep the original values of column `e` and assign the transformed values to a new column (e.g. `f`)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) to put the `e` column names at the top, making them directly accessible via indexing:

```
df = df.swaplevel(axis=1).assign(e=df.swaplevel(axis=1)['e'].apply(np.log).round(2)).swaplevel(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    a         b      
    d     e   d     e
0   1  0.69   3  1.39
1   5  1.79   7  2.08
2   9  2.30  11  2.48
3  13  2.64  15  2.77
```